# 2x2 Between Subjects experimental design with ordinal dependent variable?

Tags: categorical-data, modeling, experiment-design, ordinal-data, predictor

I have been researching for my thesis/dissertation but I guess my knowledge about this is not so wide. I am just quite confused about my model, so if you think this question is easy to answer just doing more research, I would really appreciate some references, because I really did a research and I am still lost.

I made a survey experiment, 2x2 between subject design. I have two categorical/dummies independent variables and the dependent variable is a 7-point Likert Scale (it was a single question, so maybe a likert item). Now I am not sure if I have to perform a 2x2 ANOVA due to my experiment design, or there is another way. My hypotheses make reference first to main effects (with that two independent variables) and then I have to introduce other control variables and gender as a moderator.

So, can I use ANOVA with an ordinal variable if I violate the assumptions, or should I use Kruskal-Wallis H test, or directly an ordinal regression analysis?
Sorry for the long post. I would really appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ordinal logistic regression, at least as a starting point.  If the proportional odds assumption is violated, you may need to go to some other method such as multinomial logisic.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Hope you do not mind I ask you something else. Can I study with ordinal logistic regression the main effects and interactions as I can do with ANOVA? My independent variables are coded as dummies, and I wanted to test weather there are differences between my treatments/independent variables (2x2 experiment). I do not know if I can achieve it with the ordinal model. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. There is no reason that is not possible.